# How are these line breaks being saved into MySql DB?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, line-breaks

I've got a text area that I am using JS to split into an array of each line...

```
textArray = text.split('\n');
```

At this point I would think that the lines would lose the line beak, but they dont.. so even have

```
theLine = theLine.replace(/^(\r\n)|(\n)/,'');
```

Still, when I save the line value to the database, the line break is in there!! (except the last line of course since there is no break after it.)

Comment: Why would the line breaks disappear?

Comment: @Blender I believe user12282 thought that the \n's would not appear in the array after the split, as per the String.split documentation: When found, separator is removed from the string and the substrings are returned in an array.

Comment: HA! typical!... after a day of searching, I finally break down and post the question... then immediately discover the answer.
The correct replace command that also gets that pesky line break is:

    replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

SO wont let me answer my own question so quickly, because of my newb status, so I'll post this as an answer tomorrow.... or someone go ahead and post that as the answer.

Comment: Answer your own question... or delete it ... so SO can be useful to others as a reference.

Comment: @user12282: You can simplify the regex to just `/[\n\r]/g`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct replace command that also gets that pesky line break is:

```
replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

or apparently (as per @Blenders comment)

```
/[\n\r]/g
```

though I didn't test that